# Python ConfigParser module rename a section

Tags: python, configparser

How can you rename a section in a `ConfigParser` object?

Comment: probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452788/rename-config-ini-section-using-configparser-in-python

Comment: @yuwang When you find a duplicate, please flag the question instead of posting a comment (flag link under the question). If you flag, a comment will be generated automatically and the question will enter a review queue accessible to all users that have the ability to vote to close.

Comment: possibly avoid closing as this answer contains actual code to solve the issue - not the case for the linked question

Comment: I found the answer here: http://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands. Using sub-commands resolves the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you need to

- get the sections items via [ConfigParser.items](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.items)
- remove the section via [ConfigParser.remove_section](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.remove_section)
- create a new section via [ConfigParser.add_section](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.add_section)
- Put the items back into the new section via [ConfigParser.set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.set)

Comment: i thought as much - where is cp.set_section("old_name", "new_name") when you need it?

Comment: @Heitt -- Yeah.  I've not spent a lot of time reading the configparser source, but it seems like that wouldn't be terribly hard to accomplish.  I honestly have always felt like there is a bunch of functionality to configparser which seems like it could be added without much trouble.

Answer (score 9):

example helper function - silly really but it might save someone a few minutes work...

```
def rename_section(cp, section_from, section_to):
    items = cp.items(section_from)
    cp.add_section(section_to)
    for item in items:
        cp.set(section_to, item[0], item[1])
    cp.remove_section(section_from)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the private method `_sections` to rename it in a single line.

```py
def rename_config_section(config, old_section, new_section):
    """Rename a section in a configparser object."""
    config._sections[new_section] = config._sections.pop(old_section)
```